# Creating a redshift table via a glue pyspark job

Tags: pyspark, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I am following [this blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-redshift-integration-with-apache-spark/) post on using Redshift intergration with apache spark in glue. I am trying to do it without reading in the data into a dataframe - I just want to send a simple "create table as select * from source_table" to redshift and have it execute.

I have been working with the code below, but it appears to try to create the table in the glue catalog, vs in redshift. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

```
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Replace with your Redshift JDBC URL, user, password, and driver class
redshift_jdbc_url = "jdbc:redshift://your-redshift-endpoint:5439/your-database?user=your-user&password=your-password"
redshift_user = "your-user"
redshift_password = "your-password"
redshift_driver = "com.amazon.redshift.jdbc.Driver"

# Initialize Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("RedshiftCTASExample") \
    .config("spark.jars", "path/to/RedshiftJDBC42-2.0.0.4.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Define the SQL query
query = """
    CREATE TABLE new_table AS (
        SELECT * FROM event
    )
"""

# Execute the query in Redshift
spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", redshift_jdbc_url) \
    .option("user", redshift_user) \
    .option("password", redshift_password) \
    .option("driver", redshift_driver) \
    .option("query", query) \
    .load()

# Stop the Spark session
spark.stop()
```

I should also add that I am trying to run a large number of these create table statements and I wanted to see if I can use pyspark to parallelize the requests and run them concurrently.